# Why the Rails.cache.read can't get anything in ApplicationController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a problem with my Ruby on rails application. The Ruby on Rails Cache in ApplicationController.
The data can't get, but it exists.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :init

  def init
    @setting = Rails.cache.read("data/setting")
    if not @setting
      @setting = Setting.find_create
      Rails.cache.write("data/setting",@setting)
    end
  end
end
```

Development.log show this:

> Cache read: data/setting
>
> Setting Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM > "settings" LIMIT 1
> Cache write: data/setting

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your app in development mode, it's likely that caching is turned off.  Check your  config/development.rb file for the following:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = false
```

To test your caching you can either change this value to true, or run in a different environment where caching is turned on.  I often create an environment development_as_production, pointing at the development db, but with my production.rb settings.

Answer (score 0):

I am Json, I was changed the name.

But the development environment setting current is:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = true
```

The perform_caching was trun on!
The others caches can working. only this cache didn't working (It's in the ApplicationController).

```
@setting = Rails.cache.read("data/setting")
if not @setting
  @setting = Setting.find_create
  Rails.cache.write("data/setting",@setting)
end
```

Why? Is Rails.cache.read can't working in the ApplicationController?